# How can you have text overflow on Bootstrap 3 tab?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want to change the "volume" tab into "volum..." when it goes over the screen.

Here are my codes.

```
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
  <li class="active" style="flex:1;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#client" style="text-align:center;">client</a></li>
  <li style="flex:1;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#face" style="text-align:center;">face</a></li>
  <li style="flex:1;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#pitch" style="text-align:center;">pitch</a></li>
  <li style="flex:1;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#presence" style="text-align:center;">presence</a></li>
  <li style="flex:1;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#volume" style="text-align:center;">volume</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried to add these CSS but no works, it stay the same.

```
.nav-tabs > li > a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 10em;
}
```

I have tried to add `width:100%;`/set width explicitly per each parents but no works either.

Answer (score 0):

You need `overflow: hidden; display: block;` (or `inline-block` will work, too)

```css
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
  <li class="active" style="flex:1;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#client" style="text-align:center;">client</a></li>
  <li style="flex:1;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#face" style="text-align:center;">face</a></li>
  <li style="flex:1;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#pitch" style="text-align:center;">pitch</a></li>
  <li style="flex:1;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#presence" style="text-align:center;">presence</a></li>
  <li style="flex:1;"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#volume" style="text-align:center;">volume</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/L0UgPWM.png but now the text cut even though there are still spaces to fill.

Comment: change `max-width` to whatever you need for the text you want to have ellipses.

Comment: Is there a way to do that automatically, without specifying `max-width`? I want that if it off screen then goes `text-overflow`.

Comment: @notalentgeek I don't know, you need to replicate the code in your screenshot then. What you provided doesn't put anything off screen.